# Auto copy program

Tags: pseudocode

I'm reading an article by Ken Tomson that refers to a program that, when compiled and run, generates an exact copy of its source code.

So I am thinking of how to do this in the right way.

Can anyone give me an example of this?
No need to write code, but some code can help a lot, if you prefer or if you prefer or can just give me the main ideas or the logic.
the article is called refflections on trusting trust.
[https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/thompson/trust.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/hh/thompson/trust.html)

I already have a lot of ideas but I don't know if I am correct and I need help before I start programming.

Comment: These programs are sometimes called [quines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) - that may help finding some examples and hints.

Comment: oh thanks, i just wanted a hint, and i think with this i got it.